# Refresh Token Azure Ad authentication in .Net Core 3.1 API

Tags: .net, authentication, azure-active-directory, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

Problem:-
I have a different microservice and I used Azure Ad Authentication.
Front-end create token using https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token and send to .net core api.
issue is token time out timing is 1 hr and some process running in background so some time process stop.
I need to find out refresh token in api side if token expried.

Code in start up in ConfigureServices method

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(
                        "Bearer")
                        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                        .Build();
            });
```

Configure method

```
        app.UseCustomSwagger(Configuration, provider);
        app.UseHealthChecks("/health");
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseApiVersioning();
        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
```

I have added **[Authorize]** attribute on the controller.
we have also one middleware for token add to claim

```
 public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext.User != null && httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            //string sPreferredUserName = httpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type.Equals("preferred_username", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))?.Value;
            //if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sPreferredUserName))
            //    ((ClaimsIdentity)httpContext.User.Identity).AddClaim(new Claim("preferred_username", httpContext.User.Identity.Name, ClaimValueTypes.String));

            ((ClaimsIdentity)httpContext.User.Identity).AddClaim(new Claim("Token", httpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"], ClaimValueTypes.String));
            await _next(httpContext);
        }
        else
        {
            string result1 = "UnAuthorized";
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(result1);
            await httpContext.Response.Body.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }


    }
```

I want when token and refresh token receive from front-end check token validition and if expried generate new token using refresh token.
please help
Thanks in advance

Comment: `some process running in background so some time process stop` does this mean you have a long-time process which need to use the access token continuously and whenever the token expired, the process will down? Or your process always received the same access token which stored in some where and your client don't know when the token will expire so that you need your api to check the token and let the client know when the token expired? Or something else? Could you pls add more details on your scheme or the flow of the handling progress.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**:Using `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` class. call this method to check to token valid or not

```
public bool _isEmptyOrInvalid (string token)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
        {
            return true;
        }

        var jwtToken = new JwtSecurityToken(token);
        return (jwtToken == null) || (jwtToken.ValidFrom > DateTime.UtcNow) || (jwtToken.ValidTo < DateTime.UtcNow);
    }
```

**Solution 2:**  Try with the decode the token from Base64 format you can see what the expiration date is, then you can compare it with the date right now.

If you want to check if this method works you can use [this website](https://www.base64decode.org/) to decode the token.

```
 public static bool isExpired(String token)
    {
        if (token == null || ("").Equals(token))
        {
            return true;
        }

        /***
         * Make string valid for FromBase64String
         * FromBase64String cannot accept '.' characters and only accepts stringth whose length is a multitude of 4
         * If the string doesn't have the correct length trailing padding '=' characters should be added.
         */
        int indexOfFirstPoint = token.IndexOf('.') + 1;
        String toDecode = token.Substring(indexOfFirstPoint, token.LastIndexOf('.') - indexOfFirstPoint);
        while (toDecode.Length % 4 != 0)
        {
            toDecode += '=';
        }

        //Decode the string
        string decodedString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(toDecode));

        //Get the "exp" part of the string
        String beginning = "\"exp\":\"";
        int startPosition = decodedString.LastIndexOf(beginning) + beginning.Length;
        decodedString = decodedString.Substring(startPosition);
        int endPosition = decodedString.IndexOf("\"");
        decodedString = decodedString.Substring(0, endPosition);
        long timestamp = Convert.ToInt64(decodedString);

        DateTime date = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).AddMilliseconds(timestamp);
        DateTime compareTo = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1);

        int result = DateTime.Compare(date, compareTo);

        return result < 0;
    }
```

For more details refer this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36349824/is-there-any-way-to-check-if-oauth-token-is-expired-or-not/52272882)